# Making a copy of a string in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

How do I copy two strings in assembly. I found that there is function called `str_copy`. But that seems to only available in irvine64 library. I want to achieve this in irvine32.inc

Do I need to manually write a code to make copy of a string or there is some easier way without looping n all

Comment: Any C library will have a `strcpy` function you can call.  Of course if you have explicit-length strings, you can use `rep movsb` (which is actually not too slow on modern CPUs, especially for medium to large aligned buffers.)  Otherwise yeah, you'll have to write your own strcpy, and making it efficient (copying multiple bytes per iteration) while also safe and correct is a tricky tradeoff, even with SSE2 SIMD to make detecting the terminating `0` easier.  Of course if you don't care about efficiency, copying 1 byte at a time is easy.

Comment: `str_copy` has a prototype in irvine32.inc and the name exists in irvine32.lib. Why do you think it does not exist in irvine32?

Comment: Yeah it's there. I was invoking it the wrong way. And due to the error's got confused and thought it's not there